# Recommendation letter and pay slip in Germany

Tags: germany, recommendation-letter

I quit my job on the 31.07.2017 and still haven't received my recommendation letter (Arbeitszeugnis) and pay slips (Lohnabrechnungen) for the last 4 months from my former employer. Just to be clear, I have received all my salaries, just not the pay slips which I will be needing for the tax returns. What is the legal period of time, in which he's obligated to give me these documents?

Comment: Welcome to the Workplace! Sorry but as this question is asking for specific legal information it's off-topic here, you could try over at [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) maybe?

Comment: aham, ok, 10x:)

Comment: You do not need individual pay slips. What you need is the Lohnsteuerbescheinigung, which summarizes your income and paid taxes for the whole year. They are usually sent at the end of February. For the tax return, you still have plenty of time left. Deadline for 2017 is 31. May 2018, afterwards it will be extended until 31 July each year.

Comment: This is not company-specific. This is standard for the German jurisdiction. Voting to reopen.

Comment: You could go to the Arbeitsgericht. Your employer has to provide the recommendation letter and it has to be *benevolent* and *truthful*.  He may be liable if you have problems finding a job because he failed to provide the document. @NoBackingDown has the answer to the tax-issue, and there is nothing to add (except maybe that the financial authority already got the data electronically, so you could even file your tax returns without the paper)

Comment: @Daniel Right, the Finanzamt technically already has all data in the form of the elektronische Lohnsteuerbescheinigung. However, whenever I did my taxes I had to manually copy the figures from the written Lohnsteuerbescheinigung to the ELSTER form.

Comment: @NoBackingDown: Lost mine once, just put in estimated numbers. Finanzamt adjusted for the real values and settled accordingly ...